# Not loading the sherlock theme in manifest

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-manifest

I'm trying to implement a sherlock actionbar into my application. I'm following many [tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4GJ6yY1lNNY) to implement it. But in manifest it is not showing any option for "@style/". I tried to get the answer to it. But once again I click the properties of my project and click the android button, the following error shown

[image] It is showing wrong mark in the "is library". So far I've never seen in any post. In activity it is extending(that even after clicking project fix option) sherlockactivity. Could somebody explain me what the problem is this. I already loaded the library project into workspace.I'm new to android.

Comment: What API is defined in your project.properties in the sherlock lib?

Comment: Have you imported the ABS library in your Eclipse workspace?

Comment: minsdk: 2.3. Target: 4.1.

Comment: @Siddharth Lele: First I created a project from existing code. Then Only I did the other.